# Laravel __construct() - without injecting?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am getting error:

```
GitHubApp::__construct() must be an instance of App\Project\Repositories\GitProviderRepository
```

I thought Laravel does some kind of magic when it come to `__construct()` so i don't have to inject it into `new GitHubApp();`?

```
  use App\Project\Repositories\GitProviderRepository;

    class GitHubApp
    {
        private $gitProviderRepository;

        public function __construct(GitProviderRepository $gitProviderRepository)
        {
            $this->gitProviderRepository = $gitProviderRepository;
        }
    }
```

In other class:

```
return new GitHubApp();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When calling `new GithubApp()`, you relied on yourself to build the `GithubApp` instance, Laravel does not responsible for building that instance.

You have to let Laravel resolve the dependencies for you. There are numbers of way to achieve this:

Using `App` facade:

```
App::make(GithubApp::class);
```

Using `app()` helper method:

```
app(GithubApp::class);
```

Or using the `resolve()` helper method:

```
resolve(GithubApp::class);
```

Behind the scene, your class type and its dependencies will be resolved and instantiated by the [`Illuminate\Container\Container`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php#L740-L795) class (the parent class of `Application`). Specifically by the `make()` and `build()` methods.

Hope this help! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try as:

```
return app(GitHubApp::class);
```

or

```
return app()->make(GitHubApp::class)
```

It is done by the powerful IoC container of Laravel to resolve classes without any configuration.

When a type is not bound in the container, it will use PHP's Reflection facilities to inspect the class and read the constructor's type-hints. Using this information, the container can automatically build an instance of the class.

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container#automatic-injection)

Comment: To improve your answer, please explain how your solution is differ from `return new`. What does `app()` do?

Comment: Answer updated .. If you want more information then you can read the docs, it's all there.